# Can't find ethernet packets sent by TMS570LS1227 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, texas-instruments

SOLVED: there was a setting in HALCoGen that enabled loopback mode. I am stupid.

I am attempting to send a small packet over the ethernet port on a TMS570LS1227 using a TI-provided function I'll show below. I am currently trying to read these packets by plugging an ethernet cord from the microcontroller to my laptop and monitoring "Ethernet 2" on Wireshark. However, I'm not seeing any traffic from outside the laptop.

What could be causing the packets to not send at all? I checked the number of packets received through ethernet 2 in control panel and it's zero.

Here is the sample program TI provides for this specific board that calls a few of their built-in functions:

```
_enable_IRQ();
EMACHWInit(emacAddress);
create_packet();
EMACTransmit(&hdkif_data[0], &pack[0]);
size1=600;
size2=120;
create_packet();
EMACTransmit(&hdkif_data[0], &pack[0]);
```

They create an array of 5 packets and fill them using the create_packet function. The gist of this function is

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    pack[i].tot_len = size1;
    pack[i].len = size2;
    for(j=0;j<6;j++)
    {
        data[i][j] = 0xff;
    }
    for(j=0;j<6;j++)
    {
        data[i][j+6]= emacAddress[j];

    }

    data[i][12] = 0;
    data[i][13] = 80;

    for(j=0;j<80;j++)
    {
        data[i][j+14] = i + 5;
    }

    pack[i].payload = &data[i][0];
    if(i!=4)
    pack[i].next = &pack[i+1];
    }
    pack[4].next= NULL;
}
```

From what I understand, this is setting the receiving EMAC address to 'broadcast' and the source MAC address to something specific to the board. The next two assignments are related to the length/type, and then we fill the data with junk, before chaining the 5 packets together.

I apologize if I have some fundamental misunderstanding or if it's something obvious, I'm new to microcontrollers.

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: what should I clarify?

Comment: You have no question, this is a Q&A site

Comment: I tried to make my original question clearer. On a side note, is a project like this too complex for someone new to microcontrollers? I have a computer science background but I'm having trouble just finding resources to learn this sort of thing.

Comment: It's doable, but maybe some initialization somewhere is missing or some other silly little thing is missing. Does the light come on on your computer/router when you plug in the Ethernet cable? Do they give you an example code that sends a packet? If so, does it work?

Comment: Are you using a custom board or do you have a demo kit or some other known-good hardware?

Comment: @brhans I am using the Hercules Safety MCU Dev Kit TMS570 MCU.

Comment: @user253751 oh my god I am so stupid I've been working on this for a week and there's some checkbox buried in HALCoGen that puts it in loopback mode. thank you.